# How to prove that if a continuous function satisfies $f(a b)=f(a) + f(b)$, this function must be a log function?

Tags: functions

How to prove that if a continuous function satisfies $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$ and both $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, this function *must* be a log function?  i.e., proof of uniqueness. Thanks

Comment: I think you need continuity as well, I could be wrong.

Comment: Your statement in title is different from main text.

Comment: Sorry for the confussion. The main text is my question

Comment: well zero function satisfies this as well.

Comment: If you don't assume continuity, this is false.  To build a counterexample, start with $F(x)$, additive but not linear (so $F(a+b)=F(a)+F(b)$ but $F(\lambda a)$ not always equal to $\lambda F(a)$.  Then let $f(x)=F(\log x)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$ then taking $g(x) = f(e^x)$ we get $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$ which is [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation). This equation have been discussed in many questions on this site, see [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a very good overview with many links. If $f$ is assumed to be continuous (at a single point) then the only solutions $f:\mathbb{R_{>0}}\to \mathbb{R}$ are given by $f(x) = C \log(x)$ for some constant $C$. If continuity is not assumed there there does not have to be a unique solution (see the link above for how to construct explicit examples).

See also the more directly related questions:

1. [Functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ and continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567712/functional-equation-fxy-fxfy-and-continuity)
2. [Functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ and differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380768/functional-equation-fxy-fxfy-and-differentiability)
3. [Is there another function with a property like the log?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408909/is-there-another-function-with-a-property-like-the-log)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick proof which neatly sidesteps all the $(1+1/n)^n$ stuff in Euler's original:

Let 
$$
{df\over dx} = g(x)
$$
Applying first principles
$$
{df\over dx} = \lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+h) - f(x) \over h}
$$
$$
= \lim_{h\to 0} {f(1+{h\over x})\over h}
$$
by virtue of the functional equaiton.

Now let $t=h/x$ and rewrite as a limit in $t$:
$$
{df\over dx} = \lim_{t\to 0} {f(1+t) \over tx}
$$
$$
= {g(1)\over x} \quad \text{by de l'Hopital's rule}
$$
This shows that only solutions to the functional equation have derivatives of the form $g(1)/x$.

We have a free choice of $g(1)$, which is equivalent to the choice of base for the log. Setting it to the 'natural choice' of $1$ gives us natural logs.

It's not hard to show that the differentiable solutions span all continuous solutions. Suppose there is a continuous solution $f'$. Select a value $x$ and consider the differentiable $f$ such that $f(x) = f'(x)$. Then $f$ and $f'$ must be equal for all rational powers of $x$. As these are dense, we can apply a limit to any real value and the two functions are therefore equal.

Comment: How do you get differentiability?

Comment: I didn't :-) This shows that the only $C_1$ solution is log.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you, Scott! The other solution seems good too, but I don't really know about Cauchy's functional equation. haha

Comment: However, I actually didn't really say that f has to be differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

We know that:
$f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$, that give us :

$f(1\cdot a) = f(1) + f(a)$ which give us :

$f(1) = 0$

Now : $f(\frac{1}{a} \cdot a) = f(1) = 0 = f(\frac{1}{a}) + f(a)$

Also : $f(a^{n}) = nf(a)$ , and using some kind of induction we could get: $f(a_{1}^{\alpha_{1}} \dots) = \sum \alpha_{i}f(a_{i})$.

So this function return us zero in $1$. Return us sum of power product with their multiples. And equals negate function in inverse point.

So this is $log_{a}(x)$.

Comment: Sorry for my English!

Comment: Under what assumptions does this show uniqueness?

Comment: @Farewell I use the definition of log function.

Comment: What is $a$?  In the original question, $a$ is just a variable argument for the function.  Here, it has become the base of the logarithm.  What are you assuming (or proving) about $a$?

Comment: @lulu actually this moment should be upgrade..

Comment: Ah, now your English might be an issue.  What did you mean by that?

Comment: Regardless of the question about $a$, you really do need to say something about continuity.  Your claim that $f(a^n)=nf(a)$ is fine so long as $n\in \mathbb Q$, but for general $n\in \mathbb R$ there is no reason to assume this.  Of course, continuity lets you deduce it, but the OP does not assume continuity.

Comment: @lulu But it seems that we need more than continuity, because zero function $z(x)=0$ for every positive $x$ also satisfies functional equation, right?

Comment: @Farewell  All you need is continuity plus some value for which $f(c)\neq 0$.  If I have such a $c$ then we can solve for $f(d)=1$ and that becomes the base of the log (obviously, since we can write any $x$ as $d^{\log_d x}$ so $f(x)=f(d^{\log_d x})=\log_d x$

Comment: @lulu Do you know does the functional equation implies continuity anywhere? Or we can have everywhere discontinuous solutions?

Comment: @Farewell  oh, it can be fantastically discontinuous.  Take a basis for $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, then take $f(x)$ to be the projection along one of the basis factors.

Comment: Sorry I guys, I should have said that f() is continuous.

Comment: The truly beautiful way to prove this is to go through Euler's derivation of $\int {1\over x} dx$. This shows that the integral must satisfy the functional equation, and there's a constant to resolve, which gives us $e$.