# Functions satisfying $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Are there any other functions (not necessarily continuous) satisfying $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ other than $f(x)=A \ln x$ and $f(x)=0$?

After a little thought I came to identify a function
$$f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}: z \mapsto \arg(z),$$
since $$\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2).$$
Also
$$f: A-\left\{0\right\} \to \mathbb{Z_0^+}$$ where $A$ is set of non-zero polynomials such that
$$f(x)=\operatorname{Deg}(\text{polynomial}),$$
since $$\operatorname{Deg}(h(x)g(x))=\operatorname{Deg}(h(x))+\operatorname{Deg}(g(x)).$$

Are there other functions with this property?

Comment: There is no global argument function that would satisfy this.

Comment: Let $F(x)$ be any function satisfying [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).  Then the function $f(x)=F\left(\ln (x) \right)$ satisfies your functional equation.

Comment: Worth noting:  if you add some sort of regularity condition you should be able to eliminate the pathological examples.  Continuity at a single point is probably strong enough.

Comment: The answer depends on the domain you want $f$ to have. If $0$ is in your domain, then $f(x\cdot 0)=f(x)+f(0)$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. So for your $\arg$ example, you have to at least switch to domain $\Bbb C^\times$. Even after that, $0=\arg 1=\arg((-1)\cdot(-1))\ne \arg(-1)+\arg(-1)=2\pi$

Comment: Note that assuming continuity over $\mathbb R$ and positive $x,y$, the only function that satisfied this is $\ln$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056332/how-to-prove-that-if-a-continuous-function-satisfies-fa-b-fa-fb-this?noredirect=1&lq=1).and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408909/is-there-another-function-with-a-property-like-the-log?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: The [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#p-adic_absolute_value) for primes $p$ has this property.

Comment: Any discrete valued function possible?

Comment: If $0$ is in the domain then $f(x) = f(x) + f(0) - f(0) = f(0*x) - f(0)=f(0)-f(0) = 0$.  Are we to assume the domain is closed under multiplication? I could defined  $Domain \subset \mathbb R$ so that for any $x,y \in Domain$ that $xy \not \in Domain$ and define whatever I darn well want.  And I can have some limited products.  Example $f:\{1,5,7,35,49\}$, $f(1)=0; f(5)=\pi; f(7)=2;f(35)=\pi + 2; f(49) = 4$. will work.  I could even close that under multiplication.  $Domain=\{5^n7^m\}$ $f(5^n7^m)=2n+m\pi$.  Do we assume the domain includes multiplicative inverses?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: How do you exclude logarithms with other bases?

Comment: @HenningMakholm other bases are just base $e$ times a constant, so they will work

Comment: @Holo: So I would think too. But TheSimpliFire is claiming that the natural logarithm _specifically_ is the only solution.

Comment: Let $f,g$ satisfy the condition, we can easily see that $Af+Bg$ also satisfy the condition: $H(xy)=Af(xy)+Bg(xy)=A(f(x)+f(y))+B(g(x)+g(y))=Af(x)+Bg(x)+Af(y)+Bg(y)=H(x)+H(y)$, also, like @lulu said, let $F$ be function that satisfy Cauchy's functional equation then $F\circ g$ satisfy the conditions. Also, for the positive integers it is called [Completely additive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function#Completely_additive)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function $f$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$, then $g(x)=f(e^{x})$ satisfies $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$. There are highly discontinuous functions $g$ that satisfy this identity, but they require the Axiom of Choice, which is a standard Axiom of Mathematics. For any such $g$, the function $h(x)=g(\ln x)$ is discontinuous on $(0,\infty)$ and satisfies the following
$$
         h(xy)=g(\ln(xy))=g(\ln x+\ln y)=g(\ln x)+g(\ln y)= h(x)+h(y),\;\; x,y > 0.
$$